# Using a User Control as a DataTemplate and Binding Properties

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-8

I've set up a User Control that displays a Title, Image, Collection of Players, and Time. This worked great until I stuck it into a GridView and tried to Bind these properties to the values of the elements.

Now it reports a number of errors, specifically, "The member 'X' is not recognized or not accessible". This occurs in my bindings here:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:GamePane Map="{Binding Map}" Players="{Binding Players}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

I am using DependencyProperties to try to get everything to work, like this:

```
    public string Map
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MapProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MapProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Map",                    
        typeof(string),           
        typeof(GamePane),         
        new PropertyMetadata(     
            "Unknown",            
            ChangeMap)
        );
```

This got my code compiling, however, now they just return the default value even after I have specified something different through my bindings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To understand why binding doesn't work it is important to know DataContext inheritance chain. You need to show how you set DataContext and to what object.

Comment: The binding of the GridView is done manually using a Name.ItemsSource = X statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this, as I have found what I was doing wrong.

In the User Control I set it's Data Context to itself. This was causing the issues I was having. Removing this Data Context fixed everything.